# Using std::ranges algorithms with custom containers and iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, c++20, std-ranges

I have the following simplified code representing a range of integers that I want to use with various std algorithms. I am trying to update my code to use C++20's ranges versions of the algorithms so I can delete all of the `begin()` and `end()` calls. In the below code, `std::any_of` works with my container and iterator, but `std::ranges::any_of` does not.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class Number_Iterator {
    public:
        using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = int;
        using difference_type = int;
        using pointer = int*;
        using reference = int&;

        Number_Iterator(int start) noexcept : value(start) {}
        Number_Iterator& operator++() noexcept { ++value; return *this; }
        bool operator==(const Number_Iterator& other) const noexcept = default;
        int operator*() const noexcept { return value; }

    private:
        int value;
};

class Numbers {
    public:
        Numbers(int begin, int end) noexcept : begin_value(begin), end_value(end) {}
        Number_Iterator begin() const noexcept { return {begin_value}; }
        Number_Iterator end() const noexcept { return {end_value}; }

    private:
        int begin_value;
        int end_value;
};

int main() {
    const auto set = Numbers(1, 10);
    const auto multiple_of_three = [](const auto n) { return n % 3 == 0; };

    // Compiles and runs correctly
    if(std::any_of(set.begin(), set.end(), multiple_of_three)) {
        std::cout << "Contains multiple of three.\n";
    }

    // Does not compile
    if(std::ranges::any_of(set, multiple_of_three)) {
        std::cout << "Contains multiple of three.\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile the above code, I get the following error messages from Visual Studio 2019 (16.11.15) with the flag `/std:c++20`:

```
Source.cpp(42,21): error C2672: 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found
Source.cpp(42,7): error C7602: 'std::ranges::_Any_of_fn::operator ()': the associated constraints are not satisfied
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\algorithm(1191): message : see declaration of 'std::ranges::_Any_of_fn::operator ()'
```

I have tried looking at the `std::ranges::_Any_of_fn::operator()` declaration, but I find myself more confused by that.

What am I missing to get the `std::ranges` algorithms to work with my container?

---

For the curious, what I'm actually iterating over are squares on a chess board, but those are represented by integers, so the difference from the above code isn't so great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use your range with `any_of` it must satisfy the `input_range` concept:

```cpp
template< class T >
  concept input_range =
    ranges::range<T> && std::input_iterator<ranges::iterator_t<T>>;
```

Then via the `input_iterator` concept:

```
template<class I>
  concept input_iterator =
    std::input_or_output_iterator<I> &&
    std::indirectly_readable<I> &&
    requires { typename /*ITER_CONCEPT*/<I>; } &&
    std::derived_from</*ITER_CONCEPT*/<I>, std::input_iterator_tag>;
```

and via the `input_or_output_iterator` concept

```
template <class I>
concept input_or_output_iterator =
  requires(I i) {
    { *i } -> /*can-reference*/;
  } &&
  std::weakly_incrementable<I>;
```

you land in the `weakly_incrementable` concept:

```cpp
template<class I>
  concept weakly_incrementable =
    std::movable<I> &&
    requires(I i) {
      typename std::iter_difference_t<I>;
      requires /*is-signed-integer-like*/<std::iter_difference_t<I>>;
      { ++i } -> std::same_as<I&>;   // pre-increment
      i++;                           // post-increment
    };
```

in which you see that the iterator must have both the pre-increment and post-increment versions of `operator++`.

---

The iterator must also be default constructible because `std::ranges::end` creates a sentinel:

```
template< class T >
    requires /* ... */
constexpr std::sentinel_for<ranges::iterator_t<T>> auto end( T&& t );
```

And `sentinel_for`

```
template<class S, class I>
  concept sentinel_for =
    std::semiregular<S> &&
    std::input_or_output_iterator<I> &&
    __WeaklyEqualityComparableWith<S, I>;
```

requires it to satisfy `semiregular`:

```
template <class T>
concept semiregular = std::copyable<T> && std::default_initializable<T>;
```

But without being default constructible, this substitution will fail:

```
template < class T >
concept default_initializable = std::constructible_from<T> && requires { T{}; } && ...
```

Comment: Thanks for diving through the iterator concepts. Where does the requirement for a default constructor come from?

Comment: @MarkH Good question. :-) I had to dig a lot to find it. Updated the answer.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for digging. Now I'm wondering why a sentinel iterator should be default constructible when I would think all end() iterators should be associated with some container, and thus require a unique value. But that's beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @MarkH I wondered the same thing.  It's jungle of requirements and it's easy to stray when digging around. :)

Comment: The only role of the sentinel is to determine if the end of the range is reached, which is a simple enough type to be constructed cheaply.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Indeed. I wonder how it could be used in this case though. If one does `auto e = std::ranges::end(the_set_in_the_question);` and then default construct a sentinel: `decltype(e) ed;`, then `e == ed`  will not be `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the `std::ranges` algorithms require two more methods in the iterator: a default constructor and a post-increment operator (return value optional). Adding these methods allows the code to compile and run correctly:

```cpp
Number_Iterator() noexcept : value(-1) {}
void operator++(int) noexcept { ++value; }
```